# Why Deities had more faces and humans have only one?

Tags: gods, symbolism

Brahma has 4 faces, shiva has 3 eyes , vishnu has 4 arms and many deities has many various shapes. Why? were they mutating their body or they had power of soul? Does any scripture state something about such mechanisms?

Comment: I think its symbolic

Comment: There might be some reason behind that ,which we cant understand clearly. But i think this is the way to seperate normal human beings from gods, by giving them the features that dose not normaly appear in human form.

Comment: There are many forms of Hanuman which are not famous. Panchamukhi Hanuman has five faces. See [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/17006/which-scripture-tells-the-complete-story-of-lord-hanuman/17013#17013) and Parasara samhita for more details.