# Which Scripture tells the Complete Story of Lord Hanuman?

Tags: scripture, hanuman

- We can know about Lord Hanuman from Ramayana but it states only a small portion of his life.
- Is there a scripture that tells about Lord Hanuman's story completely ?

Answer (score 6):

Valmiki Ramayana has the life of Hanuman which happened in Treta Yuga only. But the life of Hanuman is indeed wide in scope. He has been immortal since ages. He is alive even today.

**Why didn't Sage Valmiki focus on Hanuman like he did on Sita and Rama?**

Ramayana doesn't mean the story of Rama but it is the life/history of Sita.
Balakanda, chapter 4 clearly states that.

> काव्यम् रामायणम् कृत्स्नम् **सीतायाः चरितम् महत्** |
>   पौलस्त्य वधम् इति एवम् चकार चरित व्रतः || १-४-७
>
> Meaning: 
>   That sage with observed sacred vows has rendered the entire epic in the name of 'Ramayana', '**Sublime Legend of Seetha**' and 'elimination of Ravana'. [1-4-7]

So, Ramayana only discusses about Sita and Rama who is incomplete without
Sita.

**Then which scripture discusses the complete life of Hanuman?**

The answer is **Parāśara saṃhita**. The seer of this scripture is Parāśara( Father of Krishna Dwaipayana vyasa). In this scripture, life of Hanuman before Ramayana and the life of Hanuman which happened in Dwapara yuga are also present.

But some aspects in this scripture are not accepted by some people. For example  this book says Hanuman is married to Suvarchala, daughter of Sun God. On the contrary, our puranas, Mahabharata say Suvarchala is wife of Sun-God. See [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/16424/who-is-suvarchala-is-she-wife-or-daughter-of-sun-god) question for details.

Parāśara saṃhita is also translated into Telugu and English languages.

You can learn more about Parāśara saṃhita from [this](http://www.jayahanumanji.com/?p=605) page. [Here](http://sanskritdocuments.org/sanskritupload/parAsharasamhitAhanupatcharitra1.pdf) is Parāśara saṃhita in sanskrit.

Comment: lord hanuman's mother was seen by lord ram after war that means hanuman's age was equal or slightly higher(if lord ram is 25 then lord hanuman would be 30 or other) than lord rams age.As ramyana is present and why same period lord hanuman scripture is NOT AVAILABLE

Comment: @Sakthi Ramayana is Sita and Rama story. There is no need to add the role of Hanuman. Parasara maharshi wrote parasara samhita which include birth, marriage(this is not accepted by some),  life in Dwapara yuga. Click the link I have added in the answer. You will find the parasara samhita chapters. It is not available online. Hard copies are available in some book stores. You may ask the website for more details.